# Cordova-dialogs-plugin not showing when I run my code on emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm making an application and part of it requires a dialog to pop-up after my camera has taken the picture. To be more specific it's a confirmation dialog using navigator.notification.confirm

I'm stuck at the dialog part. It isn't showing up after my camera takes the picture

I tried calling the function initDialog(); in my cameraSuccess() function but it doesn't really do much. I've managed to put in just a regular alert() code in and it worked, so the problem is definitely in how I'm trying to use the dialog plugin. I even tried using innerHTML to create a button that once clicked leads to dialogs but to no avail.

```
//camera code
function cameraSuccess(imageData){
    document.getElementById("camera-picture").src= imageData;
    initDialog();
}

function cameraError(error){
    alert(error);
}

function myCameraInit(){
    console.log(navigator.camera);
    var cameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    };
    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
}

//dialogs code    
function initDialog() {
    var message = "Proceed with analysing photo?";
    var title = "Confirmation";
    var buttonLabels = "Ok, got it.";

    navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, title, buttonLabels)
}
```

The output I'm expecting is for the dialog to pop-up after my camera takes the picture. The output I'm getting is the dialog not popping up.

If the HTML code is needed please tell me and I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the device to be ready when it's in the foreground again.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, title, buttonLabels);
}, false);
```

If the above does not work, I would check your console for any errors.